# how to modify conda 'source activate' ps1 behavior

Tags: conda, bash, ps1

my current bash ps1 is as follows:

```
bldred='\e[1;31m' # Red
bldcyn='\e[1;36m' # Cyan
bldwht='\e[1;37m' # White
txtrst='\e[0m'    # Text Reset - Useful for avoiding color bleed

export PS1="\n\[$bldred\]\u\[$txtrst\]@\[$bldwht\]\h\[$txtrst\]:\[$bldcyn\]\w\[$txtrst\]$ "
```

However, running:

```
source activate <env-name-here>
```

by default, tells `conda` to prepend the `env-name` to my `PS1`:

```
(<env-name-here>)
user@short-domain:fullpath$
```

Is there a way to tell `conda` to insert the `env-name` within my `PS1` instead, specifically, right after the newline?

Comment: I don't know `conda` at all, but couldn't you just pass it the string `<env-name-here>\n` and remove the `\n` from your PS1?

Comment: @Aaron I explain how to do exactly what you described here:
 https://stackoverflow.com/q/62842563. jkarimi seems to be asking how to keep `<env-name-here>` on the same line as the rest of his prompt string, so adding a trailing newline to `<env-name-here>` would defeat the point.

Comment: Beside the point, but [you don't need to `export PS1`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/247585/117037)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The simplest solution I have found is to move the newline from `PS1` to `PROMPT_COMMAND`:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND="printf '\n'"
export PS1="\[$bldred\]\u\[$txtrst\]@\[$bldwht\]\h\[$txtrst\]:\[$bldcyn\]\w\[$txtrst\]$ "
```

This allows `conda` to maintain it's default `PS1` behavior all while separating bash commands with newlines:

```
user@short-domain:fullpath$ source activate <env-name-here>

(<env-name-here>) user@short-domain:fullpath$
```

Answer (score 19):

Conda has a setting to disable changing the prompt: [`changeps1: False` (in `~/.condarc`)](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/configuration/use-condarc.html#change-command-prompt-changeps1). You can then add this yourself (`$(basename "$CONDA_PREFIX")`).

This is similar to virtualenv, which doesn't update the prompt if `$VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT` is set, so you can print `$(basename "$VIRTUAL_ENV")` yourself.

Comment: instead of the "CONDA_PREFIX", I used the "CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER" in my PS1 for a smoother integration.

Comment: @Adriano if you don't need to insert `CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER` into the middle of `PS1`, (i.e. prepending is still okay) the Q&A I posted is even cleaner: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62842563