# iterm2 shell prompt now shows "(base)"

Tags: iterm2

I have been using iterm2 for a couple years now and its great. Lately, however, my prompt has changed in an odd way and I can't tell what it is telling me. Originally, my prompt looked like this:

`<username>@<hostname>:<current_dir>$`

Now, the prompt looks like this:

`(base) $<username>@<hostname>:<current_dir>$`

I'm running Mojave and checked my .bashrc file – everything looks normal there.

Does anyone have an idea as to what "(base)" is? What is it telling me? And how can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I did some further analysis of my .bash_profile file and I was able to isolate the `(base)` to a section that adds the Python Anaconda distribution into my path. After some further Googling, it turns out I had inadvertently created a virtual environment for my Anaconda work. This wasn't necessary, so I removed the environment by typing `source deactivate`. My terminal session now no longer shows `(base)`.

Thanks to [Blockchain Business](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51526503/why-does-base-appear-in-my-anaconda-command-prompt) for the info on how to disable a virtual environment.

Comment: This happened to me today after I did a python tutorial and installed Anaconda, so I tried this and now you have to type in `conda deactivate`. I think I probably want to disable this all together, but for now, this works.

Comment: If you want to deactivate it for all new shells, https://stackoverflow.com/a/54560785/1319850

Answer (score 14):

conda config --set auto_activate_base false

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer by editing it, such that others can learn from it

Comment: here is a bit explaination
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54429210/how-do-i-prevent-conda-from-activating-the-base-environment-by-default

Answer (score 2):

It is when you have added `conda` library to your path. Run `conda deactivate` should get rid of the (base) text from your terminal