# Anaconda client CLI installed, but anaconda command not found

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, anaconda

I would like to use the [anaconda-client CLI](https://github.com/Anaconda-Platform/anaconda-client) to access the Anaconda Cloud (specifically, to upload a local package to an Anaconda Organization), but the command is not found:

```
$ which anaconda  #empty
$ anaconda login
anaconda: command not found
```

But, the client is already installed:

```
$ conda install anaconda-client
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

# All requested packages already installed.
```

I also installed the client with pip, but the command is still not found. What am I missing?

(OS: Linux, Ubuntu 18.04)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved this by realizing that I had disabled the `base` environment from activating by default, to avoid having `(base)` display on every new terminal (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57587606/9161344)).

By manually activating the `base` environment, I was able to run the `$ anaconda login` command successfully:

```
$ conda activate base
(base) $ which anaconda
/home/username/anaconda3/bin/anaconda
```

(asking and self-answering this question for other users who have also deactivated the `base` environment by default)