# I think I've messed up my Python environment on my Mac

Tags: python, macos, installation

When I type in `which python` I get `~/opt/anaconda3/bin/python`, and that's where all packages are going. I clearly didn't know what I was doing when I installed it.

Should I try to uninstall everything and start over? I'm kind of a beginner and I feel like I've made life more difficult for myself.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with where your python is installed. It's also fine that you've installed packages on there. Moving forward, you should just create new virtual environments. When you activate your environment you can then just pip install whichever packages you want (as well as which python version) in a nice contained environment :)

Comment: Is your question related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51526503/why-does-base-appear-in-my-anaconda-command-prompt?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is No, `~/opt/anaconda3/bin/python` is the default location for python 3.6 or higher to exist when you install anaconda. Python 2.7 comes with Mac which you will most probably will not use for development and when you download anaconda it comes with python 3.9.