# How to modify conda prompt string content

Tags: bash, conda, ps1

How can I edit the conda prompt's behavior without touching my normal prompt? I want to retain conda's prepend-to-PS1 behavior, but change the string that gets prepended.

The question [how to modify conda 'source activate' ps1 behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42481726) is very similar. However, the solution there is to either inject the conda prefix into the middle of `PS1` and/or edit `PROMPT_COMMAND`. This breaks the encapsulation I want, and is very hacky when the prepend-to-PS1 behavior is still desirable.

---

My normal prompt string looks like this:

```
previous output
previous output

user@short-domain fullpath
$
```

This is the behavior I want when no conda environment is active. With a conda environment active, this becomes:

```
previous output
previous output
(<env-name-here>)
user@short-domain fullpath
$
```

I don't like how this eliminates the blank line between the previous command's output and the new prompt. Unlike the question I mentioned above, I specifically want `(<env-name-here>)` on its own line:

```
previous output
previous output

(<env-name-here>)
user@short-domain fullpath
$
```

Note how this means the conda prompt modification needs to include its own newline character. I could hack the other question's answers into working, but again, I don't want to touch any variables related to my normal prompt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a proper and very simple way to do this using conda's native
configuration options.

[Edit](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/configuration/use-condarc.html#creating-and-editing) the `.condarc` file to contain the line:

```
env_prompt: \n({default_env})
```

or run the command:

```
$ conda config --system --set env_prompt "\n({default_env})"
```

Either of these will achieve the desired effect for new terminals.
Note that the `--system` option may not be desirable for many use cases.
See the explanation below for more details.

---

### From the [conda documentation](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/index.html)

This feature can be elusive if you don't know where to look. The most
natural way to find it is to start with the [configuration section](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/configuration/index.html)
of the conda user guide.

The "using the .condarc conda configuration file" [overview](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/configuration/use-condarc.html#overview) tells
us:

> The conda configuration file, `.condarc`, is an optional runtime
> configuration file that allows advanced users to configure various
> aspects of conda, such as which channels it searches for packages,
> proxy settings, and environment directories. For all of the conda
> configuration options, see the [configuration page](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/configuration.html).

The [configuration page](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/configuration.html) describes the setting we want, along with
its default value:

```
# env_prompt (str)
#   Template for prompt modification based on the active environment.
#   Currently supported template variables are '{prefix}', '{name}', and
#   '{default_env}'. '{prefix}' is the absolute path to the active
#   environment. '{name}' is the basename of the active environment
#   prefix. '{default_env}' holds the value of '{name}' if the active
#   environment is a conda named environment ('-n' flag), or otherwise
#   holds the value of '{prefix}'. Templating uses python's str.format()
#   method.
# 
env_prompt: '({default_env}) '
```

---

### The [`conda config`](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/config.html) command

The `conda config` command is quite useful on its own. Doing

```
$ conda config --describe
```

shows the same information as the [configuration page](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/configuration.html).

Since my `.condarc` file is in a non-default location, I use the `--system` option
for `conda config` to prevent conda from creating a new `.condarc` file in my
home directory. From `conda config --help`:

```
Config File Location Selection:
  Without one of these flags, the user config file at '$HOME/.condarc' is used.

  --system              Write to the system .condarc file at
                        '<my-anaconda-install-path>/.condarc'.
  --env                 Write to the active conda environment .condarc file
                        (<current-env-path>). If no
                        environment is active, write to the user config file
                        ($HOME/.condarc).
  --file FILE           Write to the given file.
```